# Why Angular resource is attaching base url with every request?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-resource

I'm using resources angular API to gets some data from another server.

```
  function PromptService($resource,$q){   var appBaseU =
     'http//machineIp/adminapi';
         var prompts = $resource(appBaseU+'/prompt',{id:'@id'},{
           getPrompts:{
              method:'GET',

             url:appBaseU+"/prompt:id",
             params:{
               id : '@id'
             }
           }

         });
         return{
           'getPrompt':function(id){
             var defered = $q.defer();
             prompts.getPrompts(id,function(data){
              defered.resolve(data);
            },function(er){
               defered.reject(er);
             });
             return defered.promise;
           }
         }   }
```

When the request sends to the server

> http//machine-ip/adminapi/prompt

I'm using node server and node server is running on localhost. When the request sends to the server,  it attaches the localhost with URL.

> http://localhost:3000/http//machine-ip/adminapi/prompt

Comment: you should add `:` at the end of `http`.. like `http://machine-ip/adminapi/prompt` or remove the protocol part altogether like `//machine-ip/adminapi/prompt`

Comment: you forgot ":" into http://machineIp/adminapi. So it is not a valid adress.